# What is the difference between data types and literals in Java?

Tags: java, terminology

What is the difference between data types and literals in Java?

Answer (score 46):

[From Java Data types tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Data types :

> Primitive types are special data types built into the language; they are not objects created from a class

Literal :

> A [Literal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is the source code representation of a fixed value; literals are represented directly in your code without requiring computation

```
boolean result = true;

boolean - is data type
true - is literal
```

Answer (score 21):

```
 String string = "Hello World";
 <  1 > <  2 >   <     3     >
```

**1** is a data type, **2** a variable name, **3** a (String) literal

From the *JLS*:

> A literal is the source code representation of a value of a primitive type *[like `1`, `true`, `'t'`or `1.2f`]*, the String type *[like `""` or `Something`]*, or the null type 
>   *[`null`]*

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that they have enough in common to be able to identify differences, but data types are things like `int`, `float[]`, `Object`, and literals are something like `1`, `{ 1.0f, 2.0f}`, `"abcdef"`.

Answer (score 5):

Values like **1.5**, **2**, **3.13**, **“hello”** that appear **directly** in a program are known as literals.

Answer (score 4):

A literal is a constant value which is compatible to a datatype, a literal is used to assign a value to variable, to compare values or define constants.
See [JLS 3.10](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html).

**e.g:**

```
int varOfDataTypeInt = 123;

String s = "string literal";
```

Answer (score 4):

Int (Data type)    x   (Variable)         = 100  (Literals) ;

**Data type :-** Data type means type of data ,it may be `byte`, `short`, `int` , `long`, `float` , `double` ,`char` `boolean` and many other user defined type(Class) like Employee, Student etc...

**Literals :-** The value we assign to variable is called Literal .
**e.g:-** `String str= "India";` 
Here "india" is string Literal .
Literals are fixed value for a variable until they are not assign by other variable.

`true` , `false` and `null` are reserved word in java. Technically they are literals values and not keywords .However they can not be used as Identifier because they have specific  meaning to the  java Compiler.

Answer (score 2):

**Data Type:** Are nothing but a reserved memory location to store values. meaning when you create a variable you reserve some space in memory.

**Literal:** Is the source code representation of a fixed value, a Given or Constant value. **Ex:** `boolean result = true`, `String s1 = "Hello World"`.

**boolean** - is data type, result - is variable, true - is literal

**String** - is Object data type, s1 - is variable, "Hello World" - is literal

Answer (score 2):

A literal is a fixed value that is assigned to a variable (of a specific data type) directly without using a constructor

For eg:

String var1 = "Java"; -- here "Java" is a literal

String var2 = new String("Java"); -- here "Java" is not a literal

Answer (score 1):

Data types are just, well, different types of data, like `String`s or `float`s or `ArrayList`s. In Java, most data types are classes. **Edit** although according to one of the other answers, I think maybe the term "data type" might be used more for primitives, i.e. types that are not classes.

A [literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_science%29) is a way of expressing a value without having to create it using a constructor. For example, if you just put `3` in your code, it means the `int` 3. You don't have to say `new Integer(3)` or anything like that.

By the way, may I recommend the official [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Data Type :  it defines the memory assignment  for different "types" available in java.

source http://javawebtutorial.blogspot.in/2013/10/data-types-in-java-as-you-all-know-that.html

Literals : Literals in java define the actual value we can using for variables, constants or to perform any operation.

source : http://javawebtutorial.blogspot.in/2013/10/literals-in-java-literals-in-java.html