# What is difference between initialized variable and a literal in java?

Tags: java

I am learning java, while studying literals in java I found that literals can be of any datatype (int,boolean,char,etc.) and declared as

```
int decVal = 26;   //Am I declaring literal correctly?
```

As far as I know, a literal is fixed value and above declaration is very similar to initialization of a variable of 'int' type. To confirm, I tried following code.

```
public class LiteralChecking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=2;

        for(i=2;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("i= "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Where, i got output as:

```
i=2
i=3
i=4
```

now I am confused between the literal and initialization, are both same?
Can some one explain me the difference?

Comment: Did you get clarity from any of the answers below, or did we misunderstand the question somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I declaring literal correctly?

No, you're not declaring a literal. You're declaring and initializing a variable called `decVal`. `26` is an integer literal.

> I am confused between the literal and initialization

- A literal is a value in the program code. Examples of literals include

  - `"Hello"` -- A string literal
  - `true` -- A boolean literal
  - `26` -- An integer literal
- An initialization is an assignment, such as `int i = ...` where `...` is the value to initialize `i` with.

Answer (score 3):

```
int decVal = 26;
```

"int" is the datatype

"decVal " is the name of the variable

"26" is the literal

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644356/what-is-the-difference-between-data-types-and-literals-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

`26` is a literal. `true` is a literal. `54.4` is a literal.

`int decVal = 26;` is a declaration + initialization of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

A literal is a number/string/boolean that appears in your source code. `5` is an integer literal. `"Hello"` is a string literal. It *literally* means the string "Hello" - it doesn't, for example, access a variable called Hello.

`int decVal = 26;` is a declaration and initialisation of the variable `decVal`, which happens to use a literal (`26`) as the initial value.